# Why would I not get an opportunity to allow or disallow authentication using linkedin? I simply get an authenticated user automatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I am building an app using node.js and react. I have the need to authenticate users using Oauth v2 with Passport.js and MongoDB. I want to allow users to login using either Google, Facebook or LinkedIn. I have the Google authorization/authentication working great. The user fires up the app, gets a Landing page with Login options. When the Google option is selected an intermediary page is rendered, asking the user to choose their Google Account (I have 4). I select the Google account I want. The app moves on to the next page in the app. I can logout and go back to my landing page. All of that is just fine. Now if I select a login with LinkedIn (I have only 1 account), the app does not give me the intermediary page, asking me to allow (or disallow) the login. It simple and automatically gives me an authenticated user and moves on to the next page in the app. I can then logout and go back to my Landing page. So, the app is working sort of as it should be, but not entirely.

I have confirmed that when I start the login process with LinkedIn there is no item in the User Collection. I have confirmed that after the login I DO have an item in the user Collection for the Linkedin login. I have physically deleted the item (repeatedly) and retried. I get no opportunity to allow/disallow the login with Linkedin.

Here is my code:

---

services/passport.js

---

```
'use strict';

//  node modules
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy
const LinkedinStrategy = require('passport-linkedin-oauth2').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//  local modules
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id); //  NOTE: user.id = mongoDB _id
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id)
        .then(user => {
            done(null, user);
        });
});

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: keys.googleClientID,
        clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
            provider: profile.provider,
            providerID: profile.id
        })
        if (existingUser) {
            return done(null, existingUser);
        }
        const user = await new User({
            provider: profile.provider,
            providerID: profile.id,
            displayName: profile.displayName
        }).save()
        done(null, user);
    })
)

passport.use(
    new LinkedinStrategy({
        clientID: keys.linkedinAppID,
        clientSecret: keys.linkedinAppSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/linkedin/callback',
        proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({
            provider: profile.provider,
            providerID: profile.id
        })
        if (existingUser) {
            return done(null, existingUser);
        }
        const user = await new User({
            provider: profile.provider,
            providerID: profile.id,
            displayName: profile.displayName
        }).save()
        done(null, user);
    })
)
```

---

routes/auth.js

---

```
use strict';

//  node modules
const passport = require('passport');

//  local modules
const keys = require('../config/keys');

module.exports = (app) => {
    //  google routes
    app.get('/auth/google', 
        passport.authenticate('google', {
            scope: ['profile', 'email']
        })
    );

    app.get('/auth/google/callback', 
        passport.authenticate('google'),
        (req, res) => {
            res.redirect('/selector');
        }
    );

    //  linkedin routes
    app.get('/auth/linkedin', 
        passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
            request_type: 'code',
            state: keys.linkedinAppState,
            scope: ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']
        })
    );

    app.get('/auth/linkedin/callback', 
        passport.authenticate('linkedin'),
        (req, res) => {
            res.redirect('/selector');
        }
    );

    //  common routes
    app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
    });
}
```

I don't know if there is anything more you need to see. I have confirmed the the hrefs in my Header component are pointing to the correct endpoints and that they match the routes in auth.js

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation I found that there is a fair amount of interpolation that must be engaged in when using passport.js instead of manually writing the API interfaces. My problems were encountered because of incomplete setup of the various parameters for the APIs. By brute force trial and error I have solved the problems.